# SQL query for distinct row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to get the distinct row from multiple tables, depending on Job_Status.
i want to only job_status=60 and not in job_status>=90. 
Sample

```
STORENAME   JOBNO   SEQ   JOB_STATUS
ABC         743     1     20
ABC         743     2     30
ABC         743     3     60
ABC         743     4     60
ABC         743     5     90
ABC         771     1     20
ABC         771     2     20
ABC         771     3     60
ABC         771     4     60
ABC         895     1     10
ABC         895     2     20
ABC         895     3     30
ABC         895     4     30
ABC         895     5     30
ABC         895     6     30
ABC         895     7     30
ABC         895     8     20
ABC         895     9     30
ABC         895     10    30
ABC         895     11    30
ABC         895     12    30
ABC         895     13    60
ABC         895     14    90
ABC         895     15    90
```

Return expected

```
STORENAME   JOBNO   SEQ   JOB_STATUS
ABC         771     4     60
```

what i am tried is below

```
select Distinct * 
from 
(
  Select UL.StoreName, GD.Job_No, GD.STOREID, GD.Warranty 
  from dbo.SERVICEJOB GD 
  Inner Join dbo.JOBTRACKING AS JT ON JT.JOB_NO = GD.JOB_NO 
  INNER JOIN dbo.DataDetails AS UL ON GD.STOREID = UL.STOREID 
  WHERE (JT.JOB_STATUS=60) AND JT.JOB_STATUS!>90
  Group By UL.StoreName,GD.Job_No,GD.STOREID,GD.Warranty
) As U
```

For me returning all means status 90 and more also.

```html
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN Job_Status>=90 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsConsider         
    FROM SERVICEJOB GD Inner Join
dbo.JOBTRACKING  AS JT ON JT.JOB_NO= GD.JOB_NO INNER JOIN
 dbo.DataDetails AS UL ON GD.StoreID = UL.StoreID       
)
SELECT
    StoreName,
    JOB_NO,
  SEQ,
    Job_Status
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        StoreName,
        JOB_NO,
  TRACKING_SEQ
        Job_Status,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JOB_NO ORDER BY  SEQ DESC) JobPartNo
    FROM T 
    WHERE Job_Status=60
    AND JOB_NO NOT IN (SELECT JOB_NO FROM T WHERE IsConsider=0)
) AS X
WHERE JobPartNo=1
```

Comment: tried already same result.

Comment: use JT.JOB_STATUS=60 in where clause

Comment: From where comes `4190753771` in your expected result?

Comment: sorry thats copied from real result

Comment: Can you please check my answer I think it works for you

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> create table jobs (STORENAME varchar(10), JOBNO int, SEQ int, JOB_STATUS int);
> insert into jobs values
> ('ABC',   743,    1,  20),
> ('ABC',   743,    2,  30),
> ('ABC',   743,    3,  60),
> ('ABC',   743,    4,  60),
> ('ABC',   743,    5,  90),
> ('ABC',   771,    1,  20),
> ('ABC',   771,    2,  20),
> ('ABC',   771,    3,  60),
> ('ABC',   771,    4,  60),
> ('ABC',   895,    1,  10),
> ('ABC',   895,    2,  20),
> ('ABC',   895,    3,  30),
> ('ABC',   895,    4,  30),
> ('ABC',   895,    5,  30),
> ('ABC',   895,    6,  30),
> ('ABC',   895,    7,  30),
> ('ABC',   895,    8,  20),
> ('ABC',   895,    9,  30),
> ('ABC',   895,    10, 30),
> ('ABC',   895,    11, 30),
> ('ABC',   895,    12, 30),
> ('ABC',   895,    13, 60),
> ('ABC',   895,    14, 90),
> ('ABC',   895,    15, 90);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 24 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT STORENAME, JOBNO, JOB_STATUS
> FROM   jobs
> WHERE  JOB_STATUS = 60
> AND    JOBNO NOT IN (SELECT JOBNO
>                          FROM   jobs
>                          WHERE  JOB_STATUS >= 90)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> STORENAME | JOBNO | JOB_STATUS
> :-------- | ----: | ---------:
> ABC       |   771 |         60
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0a8427e79fefe1e8522a436d77220a28)*

Comment: It will not work for Seq column as OP required in final result

Comment: I know, but it returns two different SEQ for the same STORENAME, JOBNO and JOB_STATUS, a DISTINCT is not possible if OP doesn't change premises on his question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to find jobs that have a status 60 and no status > 90:

```
select job_no
from dbo.jobtracking
group by job_no
having count(case when job_status = 60 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when job_status > 90 then 1 end) = 0;
```

The complete query:

```
select ul.storename, gd.job_no, gd.storeid, gd.warranty 
from dbo.servicejob gd
join dbo.datadetails ul on gd.storeid = ul.storeid
where gd.job_no in
(
  select jt.job_no
  from dbo.jobtracking jt
  group by jt.job_no
  having count(case when jt.job_status = 60 then 1 end) > 0
     and count(case when jt.job_status > 90 then 1 end) = 0
);
```

Comment: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
getting error like this.

Comment: Well, the query looks fine to me. Both job_number and job_status are columns of table jobtracking. The first query works and the second doeesn't, I assume? Maybe SQL Server is buggy as to name scope and you need qualifiers. I have edited the second query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ROW_NUMBER()** With **Partition** and after **eliminate** rows which has JobStatus>=90

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN JobStatus>=90 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsConsider         
    FROM @tblTest           
)
SELECT
    StoreName,
    JobNo,
    Seq,
    JobStatus
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        StoreName,
        JobNo,
        Seq,
        JobStatus,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobNo ORDER BY Seq DESC) JobPartNo
    FROM T 
    WHERE JobStatus=60
    AND JobNo NOT IN (SELECT JobNo FROM T WHERE IsConsider=0)
) AS X
WHERE JobPartNo=1
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: really i dont understand your query, how i can try this.

Comment: first check with your data if it works let me know i will explain logic

Comment: sorry to ask like this what is @tblTest ?

Comment: You can replace with your table, i have test with your data and created temp table with name @tblTest

Comment: check my question. i add your answer thats what you mean?

Comment: I have give you logic and idea, it's upto you how you integrate in your Query. My query is working with your data, i have also update output